# How to make the class more cohesive?

Tags: c++, class

I'm new to coupling and cohesion concept. Given is the code of a class which obviously contains two different concepts. How can I make it more cohesive? split it into two classes? Then how these classes will communicate?

```
class order {
public:
int getOrderID();
date getOrderDate();
float getTotalPrice();

int getCustometId();
string getCustomerName();
string getCustometAddress();
int getCustometPhone();

void setOrderID(int oId);
void setOrderDate(date oDate);
void setTotalPrice(float tPrice);
void setCustometId(int cId);

void setCustomerName(string cName);
void setCustometAddress(string cAddress);
void setCustometPhone(int cPhone);
void setCustomerFax(int cFax)

private:

int oredrId;
date orderDate;
float totalPrice;
item lineItems[20];

int customerId;
string customerName;
int customerPhone;
int customerFax;
```

Now, if I create two classes `Order` and `customer` then is `customerID` be included in `Order` class as its private attribute? or just split it into two disjoint classes? How `order` class will set `customerID` when an order is placed?

Comment: You need a customer class, and your order class should store a reference (possibly a `std::shared_ptr`) to a customer.

Comment: Cohesion is usually expressed by the **S** ingle **R** esponsibility **P** rinciple (SRP) which states that a class should only do one thing. Since here you have **two** different business entities in a single object (a customer and an order) you are in trouble because: a customer could have no order (yet), a customer could have multiple orders (are you going to update all its order if the customer name change ?), an order could conceivably be linked to more entities (point of sale, payment information, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was me, a customer and an order would be two different entities. Also, as a customer can have many orders, I would have a collection of orders instead.

So something like this:

```
class Customer;  // Forward declaration of the `Customer` class
                 // So it can be used by the `Order` class

class Order
{
public:
    Order(Customer* c)
        : customer(c)
    {}

    // Other public functions...

private:
    // Other order specific data...
    Customer* customer;  // Customer for this order
};

class Customer
{
public:
    ...

private:
    // Other customer data...
    std::vector<Order> orders;  // Collection of order for this customer
};
```

Then you can simply create new orders for a single customer by adding it to the `order` collection:

```
void Customer::add_order()
{
    orders.push_back(Order(this))
}
```

Comment: An order is certainly associated with a customer, but there's a good possibility the customer is not the (sole) owner/container.

Answer (score 3):

If this is for a database application, all `order` needs is the `customer` ID, and all the customer needs is the `order` ID. When you query data, you simply cross-reference the IDs. There's no reason `order` should store customer information and vice versa, unless you want the information to be tightly coupled.

```
void createOrder() {
    Order order;
    order.customer_id = this->id;
    // something with database
}

customer.createOrder();
```

Then later on, you can get all `order`s for a certain customer this way.

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customer_id = ...
```

Comment: Really appreciate your quick response. But I still don't understand. My task is to make this class more cohesive but maintaining its functionality. What would I do? split it in two?

Comment: @user3139987 See Joachim's answer. An order shouldn't care about a customer's information, only be able to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the class into 'Order' class and 'Customer' class. (Try to follow naming conventions)

Keep a reference of a Customer object as an attribute of an Order.

You can further divide it into classes like CustomerInfo and OrderInfo which can make it easier to extend functionality in future. (low coupling)

Read these for further exploration
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns